# What I'm Losing If A Device Has JSR 82 Compatible Only With Bluetooth 1.1

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

I'm planning to buy a cellphone, this one:

http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/5130_XpressMusic/

I want to create some Bluetooth applications, but specially this one said **JSR 82 Java™ APIs for Bluetooth 1.1**. I suppose this one is limited to the 1.1 standard because the rest of the devices said **JSR 82 Bluetooth API** without any other detail.

Is this a good option? Or should I choose another device without the **Bluetooth 1.1** constraint?

Comment: Which other devices did you look at?

Comment: Mmm, maybe Nokia 2630 ( http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/2630/ ), but the Nokia 5130 XpressMusic has more features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.1 in there actually refers to the version of the Java Bluetooth API, not the version of Bluetooth, so a device saying 1.1 should actually be better than a device without a version number (as that indicates 1.0).

Comment: @jk thank you very much, so I can continue my plan of buying one.